# Submanifolds and tangent spaces from Zorich's book

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, differential-geometry, manifolds

I was reading few pages from Zorich's book about submanifolds and I spent some time trying to understand and I think that I succeeded but there are still questions which I cannot answer myself. So I would be very thankful if someone can help me!

First of all, author gives a definition of a $k$-dimensional smooth manifold.

> **Definition 1.** We shall call a set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ a $k$-dimensional smooth surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (or a $k$-dimensional
> submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$) if for every point $x_0\in S$ there
> exist a neighborhood $U(x_0)$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and a diffeomorphism
> $\varphi:U(x_0)\to I^n$ of this neighborhood onto the standard
> $n$-dimensional cube $I^n=\{t\in \mathbb{R}^n: |t^i|<1,\  i=1,\dots,n\}$
> of the space $\mathbb{R}^n$ under which the image of the set $S\cap
>  U(x_0)$ is the portion of the $k$-dimensional plane in $\mathbb{R}^n$
> defined by the relations $t^{k+1}=0,\dots, t^n=0$ lying inside $I^n$.

Then the provides the following

> **Example.** Let $F^i(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ $(i=1,\dots,n-k)$ be a system of smooth functions of rank $n-k$. One can show that the relations $$
>  \begin{cases} F^1(x^1,\dots,x^k,x^{k+1},\dots,x^n)=0,\\
>  \dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\\
>  F^{n-k}(x^1,\dots,x^k,x^{k+1},\dots,x^n)=0 \end{cases} \quad \quad \quad (1)$$ define a
> $k$-dimensional submanifold $S$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

So far so good. Then he discusses the notion of tangent space which confused me a bit.

> **Definition 2.** If a $k$-dimensional surface $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n,1\leq k\leq n,$ is defined parametrically in a
> neighborhood of $x_0\in S$ by means of a smooth mapping
> $(t^1,\dots,t^k)=t\mapsto x=(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ such that $x_0=x(0)$ and
> the matrix $x'(0)$ has rank $k$, then the $k$-dimensional surface in
> $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined parametrically by the matrix equality $(2)$ is called
> the *tangent plane* or *tangent space to the surface* $S$ *at* $x_0\in S$.
> $$x-x_0=x'(0)t \quad \quad(2)$$
> In coordinate form the following system of equations corresponds to equation $(2)$:
> $$\begin{cases}
> x^1-x^1_0=\frac{\partial x^1}{\partial t^1}(0)t^1+\dots+ \frac{\partial x^1}{\partial t^k}(0)t^k,\\
> \dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots \\
> x^n-x^n_0=\frac{\partial x^n}{\partial t^1}(0)t^1+\dots+ \frac{\partial x^n}{\partial t^k}(0)t^k.
> \end{cases} \quad \quad \quad (3)$$
> We shall denote the tangent space to the surface $S$ at $x\in S$ by $TS_x$.

Then author asks the following question: *how to write the equation of the tangent space for submanifolds in the above example?*

> One can determine the form of the equation of the tangent plane to the
> $k$-dimensional surface $S$ defined in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by the system $(1)$.
> One can show that the equation for the tangent space $TS_{x_0}\subset
>  \mathbb{R}^n$ is $$F'_x(x_0)(x-x_0)=0. \quad \quad \quad (4)$$ In coordinate
> representation equation (4) is equivalent to the system of equations
> \begin{cases} \frac{\partial F^1}{\partial
>  x^1}(x_0)(x^1-x^1_0)+\dots+\frac{\partial F^1}{\partial
>  x^n}(x_0)(x^n-x^n_0)=0,\\
>  \dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\dots\\
>  \frac{\partial F^{n-k}}{\partial
>  x^1}(x_0)(x^1-x^1_0)+\dots+\frac{\partial F^{n-k}}{\partial
>  x^n}(x_0)(x^n-x^n_0)=0 \end{cases}

Then he adds one more paragraph which confused me completely.

> The affine equation $(4)$ is equivalent (given the point $x_0$) to the
> vector equation $$F'_x(x_0)\cdot \xi=0, \quad \quad \quad (5)$$ in
> which $\xi=x-x_0$. Hence the vector $\xi$ lies in the plane $TS_{x_0}$
> tangent at $x_0\in S$ to the surface $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ defined
> by the equation $F(x)=0$ if and only if it satisfies condition $(5)$.
> Thus $TS_{x_0}$ can be regarded as the vector space consisting of the
> vectors that satisfy $(5)$.

Here is my question which bothers me a lot: So what is $TS_{x_0}$?
First he defined it as $$TS_{x_0}:= \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: F'_x(x_0)(x-x_0)=0\}.$$

Then he somehow says that $$TS_{x_0}:= \{\xi\in \mathbb{R}^n: F'_x(x_0)\cdot \xi=0\}.$$

But obviously they are different objects. Can anyone explain where is my misunderstanding please?

I would be deeply thankful for the help since I am struggling with this a few days. But please do not use anything advanced. I would be happy to see the explanation within given definitions which I provided above.

**EDIT:** All this is from Zorich's book (volume 1, Chapter 8, Topic 8.7.1 $k$-Dimensional surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$).

Comment: Read carefully the discussion around (5). Most of us expect the tangent space of a submanifold to be a *vector subspace* of $\Bbb R^n$. However, here he's discussing the "calculus" notion of the tangent plane, which is based at the point $x_0$, rather than going through the origin. Note that he then "regards" $TS_{x_0}$ as the shifted *vector space* through the origin. I agree that this is confusing. I used to differentiate between tangent *plane* and tangent *space* when I taught this.

Comment: @TedShifrin, I am reading that part around (5) again and again the last few days and trying to understand maybe I missed something but it is unsuccessful so far. If you have any sensible explanation it would be great to read it. Thank you!

Comment: He, unfortunately, is using the same notation for the affine subspace and the linear subspace parallel to it. Since we are going to talk about linear maps from tangent space to tangent space, we really want to forget about the affine subspace — other than thinking about the best linear approximation to the submanifold at $x_0$ — and work exclusively with the subspace through the origin parallel to it. When I write $TS_{x_0}$ that's always what I intend. I would recommend that you not get too bogged down in this.

Comment: @TedShifrin, sorry but i am still confused with your comment. I am wondering can you give answers to my questions?

Comment: I suggest drawing a picture when $n=2$ and $k=1$.

Comment: You should also explictly say which of Zorich's books you mean and where precisely definitions  and examples can be found.

Comment: @PaulFrost, sorry about that! I forgot to mention it. Please the EDIT in the topic. It would be great if you can clarify my questions please.

Comment: @Deane, Thank you! But I don't think that it is helpful. But anyway, I followed your advice and considered the case when $n=2,k=1$. In that case we have $S\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ defined as $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: F(x,y)=0\}$, where $F$ is a smooth function. Assume that $F(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1$, i.e. $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x^2+y^2=1\}$ is a 1-dimensional surface in $\mathbb{R}^2$, i.e. unit circle. Let $(x_0,y_0)=(1/2,\sqrt{3}/2)\in S$. In that case tangent space is $TS_{(x_0,y_0)}=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2: x+\sqrt{3}y=2\}$. But Zorich gives different definitions that is why I am confused.

Comment: The tangent space at a point is the set of all possible velocity vectors of curves passing through the point. It is a vector space that includes the zero vector. What you’re calling the tangent space is the line parallel to tangent space passing through the point. It’s useful for visualizing what the geometric meaning of the tangent space is but it’s not literally the tangent space.

Comment: @Deane, so do you mean that something is wrong with Zorich’s definition?

Comment: Well, as you already know, the two definitions are inconsistent. So they can’t both be right.

Comment: @Deane, yeah agree. I am still thinking how to fix these definitions. Spent so much time learning this and I would like to understand it properly eventually)

Comment: Only one of the definitions is a vector space.

Comment: There are two conflicting definitions of the tangent space. Only one of them is a vector space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zorich's notation is indeed ambiguous and may lead to confusion (as your question shows).

Actually he introduces two different concepts, but does not properly explain what the difference is. More sharply formulated, he fails to give precise definitions.

1. The tangent plane.

This concept first occurs on p.471 where he defines the tangent plane to the graph $S$ of a real-valued function defined on an open subset of $\mathbb R^2$. He calls $S$ a *surface* in $\mathbb R^3$. The tangent plane at $\xi_0 \in S$ is an affine plane in $\mathbb R^3$, but in general not a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. Intuitively we can understand it as the affine plane which best approximates $S$ in a neighborhood of $\xi_0$.

In section 8.7.1 the above concept of "surface" is generalized to that of a *$k$-dimensional smooth surface in $\mathbb R^n$* and in section 8.7.2  the *$k$-dimensional tangent plane to a $k$-dimensional smooth surface in $\mathbb R^n$* is introduced. This is again an affine subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.

2. The tangent space .

This concept occurs first on p.435:

> We remark that the differential is defined on the displacements $h$ from
> the point $x \in \mathbb R^m$. To emphasize this, we attach a copy of the vector space $\mathbb R^m$ to the point $x \in \mathbb R^m$ and denote it $T_x\mathbb R^m, T\mathbb R^m(x)$, or $T\mathbb R^m_x$. The space $T\mathbb R^m_x$ can be interpreted as a set of vectors attached at the point $x \in \mathbb R^m$. The vector space $\mathbb R^m$  is called the tangent space to $\mathbb R^m$ at $x \in \mathbb R^m$. The origin of this terminology will be explained below.

This is a bit confusing. An object $T\mathbb R^m_x$ is defined as the set of vectors attached at the point $x \in \mathbb R^m$ (whatever the precise meaning may be), on the other hand $\mathbb R^m$ itself is called
the tangent space to $\mathbb R^m$ at $x \in \mathbb R^m$.

A bit more information is given in section 8.7.2, but in my opinion it is still confusing. In Definition 2 we can read

> ... the $k$-dimensional surface in $\mathbb R^n$ defined parametrically by the matrix equality (8.141) is called the *tangent plane* or *tangent space* to the surface $S$ at $x_0 \in S$.

This suggests that *tangent plane* and *tangent space* are synonyms, but they are not. Zorichs's use of the two phrases is inconsistent. He says that (8.152) defines the tangent space $TS_{x_0}$ which means that
$$TS_{x_0} = \{ x \in \mathbb R^n \mid F'_x(x_0) \cdot (x -x _0) = 0 \} .$$

Later he says that the affine equation (8.152) is equivalent (given the point $x_0$) to the vector equation (8.154) in which $\xi = x - x_0$. This is correct, but then he writes

> Hence the vector $\xi$  lies in the plane $TS_{x_0}$ tangent at $x_o \in S$ to the surface $S \subset \mathbb R^n$ defined by the equation $F(x) = 0$ if and only if it satisfies condition (8.154). Thus $TS_{x_0}$ can be regarded as the vector space consisting of the vectors $\xi$ that satisfy (8.154). It is this fact that motivates the use of the term *tangent space*.

This is plainly false. The set $TS_{x_0}$ is an affine subspace (which in general does not contain the origin) whereas the vector space consisting of the vectors $\xi$ that satisfy (8.154) is
$$\{ \xi \in \mathbb R^n \mid F'_x(x_0) \cdot \xi = 0 \} .$$
This is a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and **the standard** is to call it the tangent space to $S$ at $x_0 \in S$.

Both objects (tangent plane and tangent space) carry the same information, but the tangent plane $TS_{x_0}$ is obtained from the tangent space via a translation by $x_0$. Here is an example.
[image]

The tangent space at $x_0$ is the one-dimensional linear subspace (= line through the origin) parallel to $TS_{x_0}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for such a detailed answer! I think now I understood these two notions much better. Just to be sure let me ask you a few questions: if $S\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a smooth $k$-dimensional submanifold and $x_0\in S$, then there exists a neighborhood $U(x_0)$ of $x_0$ such that $S\cap U(x_0)=\{x\in U(x_0): F(x)=0\}$, where $F=(F^1,\dots,F^{n-k})$.

Comment: Am I right that in this case a tangent plane to $S$ at point $x_0$ is $\mathcal{P=}\{x\in \mathbb{R}^n: F'_x(x_0)(x-x_0)=0\}$ and tangent space is $TS_{x_0}=\{\xi\in \mathbb{R}^n: F'_x(x_0)\cdot\xi=0\}$. So we see that $TS_{x_0}$ is a linear subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathcal{P}=x_0+TS_{x_0}$. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @ZFR Yes to both questions!

Comment: Dear Paul! That was a great answer which completely answered all my questions and doubts! I am accepting your answer! Thank you very much!